# how to get pixel by pixel values from a YUY2 yuyv422 raw video?

Tags: shell, imagemagick, pixel, video-processing

I have a video (extension is .ravi) that is the output of a IR camera software.
I need to compute the temperature from each pixel for each frame within that video.
The IR camera+software company already told me they would not help since such information would reveal much of their know-how.

When I play the video, e.g. in mplayer, the temperature fields seem to display correctly. So the information that translates into a pixel color contains the information on its temperature.

My idea is to isolate each frame into a file, find the pixel information for each pixel in each file. I am able to retrieve the temperature pixel by pixel for single frames with the original IR Camera software (though this is done by point and click, unfeasible for each frame). Then, with the pixel information on the one side, and the temperature information on the other side (both for the first frame), I hope to relate them by a function and hopefully that function applies to all the frames of the video.

For that video, I get the following metadata (from FFMEPG):

```
Metadata:
META            : (640,480,16,312500),(0,0,0,0),0,1,80
Duration: 00:13:53.06, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 158338 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x481, 157619 kb/s, 32 fps, 32 tbr, 32 tbn, 32 tbc
```

I guess the color I see when playing the video, which is somehow related to the pixels temperature, comes from the YUV values for each pixel.

How can I access that information?

I have tried to convert each frame to an image (say PNG) with FFMPEG, and then get the value for each pixel (e.g. using ImageMagick), but I get RGB values.

Following @VC.One advice I can convert every frame to a single file:

```
ffmpeg -i original.ravi -c copy -pix_fmt yuyv422 frame%05d.bmp
```

(If I use .yuv as extension instead of .bmp I get a single file, and not a file for each frame.)

Now, with a file for each frame, I can look at it with ImageMagick:

```
convert -size 640x481 -depth 8 -sampling-factor 4:2:2 YUV:frame00001.bmp -colorspace YUV frame00001.txt
```

and this is how the output looks like:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 640,481,65535,yuv
0,0: (12436,26650,58361)  #3068E3  yuv(48,104,227)
1,0: (6314,29662,45762)  #1973B2  yuv(25,115,178)
2,0: (15547,25111,19123)  #3C624A  yuv(60,98,74)
```

From the documentation I understand this information as follows:

- first line, the header, contains information on the number of pixels (640x481) and the maximum value for each YUV field: 65535 (this I guess comes from the -depth 8 option)
- then, for each pixel, a line: its position, the YUV values into brackets,
- then as a comment the RGB value
- and then something else I do not understand.

Are the single frames really saved as yuv files, even though they have the .bmp extension?
Do I read properly the output of ImageMagick?

Comment: Please tag question with your programming language. Also why not convert the RGB value into YUV? (_eg:_ https://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have been using the command line so far, so I guess the programming language is zsh. This might be very basic: how can I be sure the yuyv422 I obtain from the RGB value is the same as the one in the original video?

Comment: Note that a max. value of 65535 would mean a depth of 16, not 8 (which max. is 255).

Answer (score 1):

**(1)**

> *"I would like to, for each frame of the video, have the luminance and chrominance values for each pixel."*

First... Get the video into single frames via FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -framerate 32 -s 640x481 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i input.yuv -c copy frame%d.yuv
```

This will output each frame as an individual `YUV` (*eg:* *frame01.yuv*, *frame02.yuv*). Note: there is no header about picture width or height, so later you must specify image size whenever using the YUV file.

Second... Getting pixel values:

I don't use ImageMagick but from a [quick research](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#txt) of the manual:

```
convert -size 1024x768 -colorspace YUV frame01.yuv output01.txt
```

The above is untested and it's possible you need also `-sampling-factor 4:2:2` or even `-depth 8` as input options. You have more experience than me with this program. Maybe even try as:

```
convert -size 1024x768 -depth 8 YUV:frame01.yuv -colorspace YUV output01.txt
```

> *"...How can I be sure the yuyv422 I obtain... is the same as the one in the original video?"*

You could open each YUV file in hex editor to see the YUV data as byte values (or find a command line tool that prints binary data).

For example a yellow pixel looks like:

RGB (24): `[FF] [F2] [00]`... where red=FF (255), green=F2 (246), blue=00 (0).

YUYV422 (16): `[CB] [13] [CB] [96]`... where Y0=CB (203), U0=13 (19), Y1=CB (203), V0=96 (150).

So starting at index 0 for first pixel, the lum (Y) is 203 and ChromaB (U) is 19, skip one byte (*ie:* the third byte) and get ChromaR (v) = 150. So first pixel YUV is `[CB][13][96]` within bytes of the frame's YUV data.

The second pixel starts with that third byte `[CB]` that was previously skipped. 
See image below for YUV byte structure...

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks very much @VC.One for your explanation.
I had gotten as far as extracting each frame into a file with yuv-defined pixels (my code is a bit different from yours): `ffmpeg -i raw.yuv -c copy -pix_fmt yuyv422 frame%05d.bmp`.
My limitation was that I was not supplying ImageMagick with enough information on the single frame files.
Now, using the convert command, I get slightly different results depending on which flag is used or not. However, only when using `-depth 8` and `-sampling-factor 4:2:2` were there no error warning.
Still trying to understand what the exported data means.

Comment: (1) Outputting as `.bmp` will give R-G-B values (as expected in BMP format) not giving Y-U-V values. Your questions says you want _"the luminance and chrominance values"_ so output as `.yuv`. (2) Given for example a red pixel (as `#FF0000` or decimal `255, 0, 0`) what is you expected result? RGB `255, 0, 0` becomes YUV `76, 84, 255` is that what you want, when you say _"luminance and chrominance"_? (3) Show a small example of exported data for possible advice (update your question). No idea what you're seeing on your screen.

Comment: PS: When you update question, also mention your project's goal or purpose. When you get this info from pixel, what will you use it for? It's possible that maybe just getting HSL values (not YUYV) from pixel is enough for your project's needs. From each pixel's R-G-B values you could calculate the **H**ue (color), **S**aturation and **L**uminance. Basically RGB / HSL / YUV all have different ways to hold/calculate the information of a pixel's color and it's luminescence (no need to be unsure if green from RGB is same green from YUV, just do conversion maths via algorithm)

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much for your answer. I have tried to output to `.yuv` but the output is a single file, not a file for each frame. I will now update the question.